# Why chrome doesn't (seem to) need Flash while Firefox and Safari do?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, flash, safari

I have a newly installed OS (OS X Yosemite)

I downloaded the Chrome and Firefox browsers, in addition to the pre-installed Safari browser.

Now flash videos work fine with Chrome, but both Safari and Firefox ask me to install Flash.

Why is this? (I would rather not install Flash if I don't have to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome comes with its own built-in Pepper Flash Player, so there is no need to install an additional Adobe Flash Player if Google Chrome is the only web browser that you are using. In your case, you need to also install Adobe Flash Player in order to play flash videos in Safari and Firefox.

Updates to Google Chrome will sometimes be accompanied by updates to Chrome's built-in flash player, which keeps it as/almost as up-to-date as the latest version of Adobe Flash Player.

Comment: The current version of the built-in Pepper Flash Player in Chrome 46 is version 19.0.0.207.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome installs its own flash plugin.
In OSX it's called PepperFlashPlayer.plugin and you can check it on chrome://plugins/